# Reverse engineering in Bouml for php project

Tags: zend-framework, reverse-engineering, uml, class-diagram

My php project using Zend framework. i want to generate class diagram for that php(zendframwork). i try to generate class diagram using Bouml project.

I go through this link [Boumal java reverse engineering video](http://youtu.be/fRp0ARbEdMg)
but problem is when i drag and drop every php class but that don't show relationship between class

Comment: @Manuel: thanks your feed back. **UML Lab** good for clz diagram. but some of relationship don't show in generated diagram.hey is that support **sequence diagram** generation for php project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could give UML Lab (http://uml-lab.com) a try (Note: I'm biased as I'm working for Yatta Solutions ;) ). There is a tutorial explaining how to reverse engineer existing source code: http://www.uml-lab.com/en/uml-lab/tutorials/reverse-engineering-tutorial/. Basically, just create a new Model and Class Diagram and all available PHP source files are imported automatically. Otherwise you can import a PHP file by dragging it onto the diagram editor.

The tool supports Java and PHP, and has build-in support for Zend Framework. It may not understand each PHP source file - but files containing a class should work fine. If there is something the tool doesn't understand you'll be notified and can directly file a bug.

It's a commercial tool, but there is a 30 days trial and a free academic edition. If you have any questions don't hesitate asking them in the forum, bug tracker or by mail.

Comment: By the way: I could reverse engineer it for you to give you a impression of uml lab if you want. You'd just have to upload your code somewhere.

Comment: how can i generate sequence diagram in php project?

Comment: UML Lab currently supports modeling of software structure: UML Class Diagrams and UML Package Diagrams. Sequence Diagrams are currently only on the roadmap of UML Lab ;)

Answer (score 1):

each time you add a class in a class diagram the relations with the already present classes are shown, except of course if you modified the "drawing settings" to not draw automatically the relations.

but this supposes there are relations to draw ;-)

Php is a not typed language, so the reverse can only create inheritances, the types of the attributes are unknown contrarily to C++ or Java

Comment: what kind of relation i want to draw give the simple example. my diagram only show extended class and package relationship with class